# how to annotate class and subclasses ? python

Tags: python, typing

how to annotate an argument that is supposed to be a class or its sub-classes ? Not using Union since this is not elegant.

Let's have a minimal example :

```
class Point:
   def __init__(self,x,y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y

class Segment(Point):
   def __init(self,point1,point2):
      self.p1 = point1
      self.p2 = point2

def random_function(point_or_segment : Point_and_subclasses):
   pass
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `Segment` should be a subclass of `Point` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the type would look like

```
from typing import Type

def random_function(point_or_segment: Type[Point]):
```

which denotes `point_or_segment` should be an instance of `Point` or an instance of a subclass of `Point`.

From the [docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#the-type-of-class-objects)

> Sometimes you want to talk about class objects that inherit from a given class. This can be spelled as `type[C]` (or, on Python 3.8 and lower, `typing.Type[C]`) where `C` is a class. In other words, when `C` is the name of a class, using `C` to annotate an argument declares that the argument is an instance of `C` (or of a subclass of `C`), but using `type[C]` as an argument annotation declares that the argument is a class object deriving from `C` (or `C` itself).